# Responding to a Triggered Ability, multiple times

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

My opponent is at 3 life and has a [Dread](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=140168) on board. I have a [Fungal Plots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFungal%20Plots%5d), and a [Slimefoot, the Stowaway](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSlimefoot%2c%20the%20Stowaway%5d), a 1/1 green Saproling token, and 8 mana open.

- I attack with my token, and he blocks. My token dies, triggering Slimefoot's effect.
- When Slimefoot's triggered effect resolves, this damage triggers Dread's effect.
- In response to Dread's triggered effect, I use Slimefoot's token generation activated ability twice.
- Then once those token generation effects resolve but before Dread's ability does, I use Fungal Plots to sac those tokens, triggering Slimefoot's effect two more times, for lethal.

Is my understanding of the rules correct that I can make this line of play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every time something on the stack resolves, there's another round of priority before the next thing resolves, so you can activate your creatures' abilities before the "destroy Slimefoot, the Stowaway" effect resolves.

Comment: @Andrew I may be missing something, but I don't see any reason that attacking was required to do the combo. You do need all the deaths to occur together so that they can resolve before the "destroy Slimefoot, the Stowaway" effect resolves, but the creation of the tokens can happen at any time.

Comment: @Andrew Perhaps your comments are based entirely on Arcanist Lupus' comment, and not on reading the answer before it was edited?